# How to slowdown zoom in and zoom out speed in Android Unity3D for mobile phones

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Here is the code I am using

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;


public class PinchZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
public Canvas canvas; // The canvas
public float zoomSpeed = .000000000000000001f;        // The rate of change 
of the canvas scale factor

void Update()
{
    // If there are two touches on the device...
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - 
        touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - 
        touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the 
      touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - 
         touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - 
     touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        // ... change the canvas size based on the change in distance 
        between the touches.
        canvas.scaleFactor -= deltaMagnitudeDiff * zoomSpeed;

        // Make sure the canvas size never drops below 0.1
        canvas.scaleFactor = Mathf.Max(canvas.scaleFactor, .7f);
     }
    }
  }
```

I tried adding zeroes to value of zoomSpeed and also tried making it negative but the zoom in and out speed is still too fast. I want the speed to be a lot slower.

Comment: This is for a mobile phone. Its a pinch to zoom function.

Answer (score 0):

I am such an idiot. I have been trying to change the zoomSpeed value in the c# code. In Unity, in the main camera component where I added the c# script. There is Zoom Speed and that's the value that needs to be change. It was so simple but I am total beginner that I didn't know that.